# Creating list menu runtime using Jscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I am stuck while creating List (Ul li),infact this is a menu pupolating at runtime.

Like

```
.Computers items
.Keyboard
.Cd rom
.office Equipment
.item 1
.item 2
.item 3
.item 4
.item 5
```

problem is, when i tryied to add new

at run time (after click on any category for example Computers)then it adds new items in same (parent) 
anyone can help me out. thanks

I am using this code

```
$("#cssmenu ul").append('<li class="active has-sub" id="'+ id.toString()+'" onclick="My_Func($(this).html(),this.id)"><a href="#"><span>'+txt +'</span></a>');
```

Comment: wrap it in a ul and append to that ul.

Comment: abih: i am having problem to send ID on click event and then track the element to fill that with new values

Comment: Added as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first wrap the contents of your first-level `li` (i.e. the ones you want to be click-able and load data) in `a`. This will save you from the frustration of multi-level `li` targeting. Also give a unique `id` to your `li` so as to load corresponding data.

Then, bind to the click event on those `a` and create a `ul`. Load data into `li` and append them to this `ul`. Once done, append this `ul` into the currently clicked `li`.

***This snippet will make it clear to you:***

For the purpose of this demo, we loading data from an object dictionary which contains the contents of each *category* as an array.

```js
/* For the purpose of this demo, data is stored in this object */
var items = {
 "computers": ['Computer 1', 'Computer 2', 'Computer 3'],
 "equipment": ['Eq 1', 'Eq 2'],
 "peripherals": ['CD', 'Printer', 'etc']
};

/* Target the a which are direct children of li which are direct children of list ul  */
$("ul#list > li > a").on("click", function(e) {
  
    // When a is clicked, we get the id of parent li
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
  
    // Create a ul
    var $wrap = $("<ul />");
  
    // Loop thru data, or loaded thru other means
    for (var idx in items[id]) {
      
        // Create li from data and append to ul
        $wrap.append("<li>" + items[id][idx] + "</li>");
    }
  
    // append this ul to the current li
    $(this).parent().append($wrap);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
    <li id="computers"><a href="#">Computers</a></li>
    <li id="equipment"><a href="#">Equipment</a></li>
    <li id="peripherals"><a href="#">Peripherals</a></li>
    <li>Others</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Abih!
I am trying to run this code at my side but its not loading details  i dont know y but i am trying Thanks Again.....

Comment: How are you loading your data? From where is that coming from?

Comment: it from SQL server, now am running same code and onclick its not riggers the event and no loading performs...

Comment: In that case plug this code in, when your ajax call returns.